# Best way to store a pointer to base class, but be able to use derived class functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a `Cell`, which can store objects of `CellContent` type. `CellContent` have to be a virtual class. From `CellContent` I have to derive classes `Enemy` and `Item`. So the idea is to store a pointer to a `CellContent` inside of `Cell`. The question is: what is the best way to store a pointer to a derived class in this circumstances?

My current solution is not an elegant one and I want to improve it.

```
class Cell
{
public:
  template<class T> void setCellContent(std::shared_ptr<T> cellContent)
  {
    _cellContent = std::dyanmic_pointer_cast<CellContent>(cellContent);

    if (std::is_same<T, Enemy>::value = true) {
      _cellContentType = CellContentType::ENEMY;
    } else if (std::is_same<T, Item>::value = true) {
      _cellContentType = CellContentType::ITEM;      
    }
  }

  template<class T> std::shared_ptr<T> getCellContent()
  {  
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(_cellContent);
  }

  CellContentType getCellContentType()
  {
    return _cellContentType;
  }

  std::shared_ptr<CellContent> _cellContent;
  CellContentType _cellContentType;
}

int main()
{
  auto enemy = std::make_shared<Enemy>();

  Cell cell;
  cell.setCellContent<Enemy>(enemy);

  if (CellContentType::ENEMY == cell.getCellContentType()) {
    cell.getCellContent<Enemy>();
  } else if (CellContentType::ITEM == cell.getCellContentType()) {
    cell.getCellContent<Item>();
  }
}
```

How I can avoid use `if` this ugly if in main?

Comment: Normal polymorphism with virtual functions?

Comment: Looks like a classic violation of [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: As a general rule, a given class should either be designed for dynamic or static polymorphism. Here, removing templates and use virtual functions seem to be the appropriate choice.

Comment: @Phil1970, So all functions, which can be used in a derived class shoud be declared virtual in the base class?

Comment: Yes, this is how virtual functions work. Virtual inheritance is a complex topic on its own, see your textbook for more information. Stackoverflow isn't really a very good replacement for a good C++ textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All functions of the derived-class, which:

- Need to be callable,
- While variable is of base-class-type,
- But without casting from base-class-type to derived-class-type manually,

should be declared `virtual` in the base-class (and be overridden in derived-class).